# Changing the background colour of another element on click

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to add accessibility options to a website to give the user the chance to change the background of the following element (not the whole document background):

```
   .ast-separate-container .ast-article-single {
    background-color: #fffff0;
    }
```

For example, I would like to display coloured boxes or text for:
Pink White Blue Yellow
and when the links are clicked the background colour changes.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML/Javascript you used to see where you might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should use JS and add event listener to this component:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  element.classList.add(/* class with corresponding styles */)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code snippet, which uses javscript to achieve that:

```js
var background = document.getElementById('background');

function setBackgroundTo(color) {
  background.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```css
#background {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
The div below simulates your background. Click a button to change its color.

<div id="background"></div>

<button onclick="setBackgroundTo('red')">Red</button>
<button onclick="setBackgroundTo('blue')">Blue</button>
<button onclick="setBackgroundTo('green')">Green</button>
<button onclick="setBackgroundTo('#000')">Black</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can see from the code snippet that your answer changes the colour of a fixed height and width area. I am not sure how to get the cream colour area of this page to change colour: http://walkerwebsites-test.co.uk/test2/